# Nodejs: merge join mulitple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

consider this scenario:

I have 2 csv files, each one is sorted and contains the `id` filed.
I need to join the rows using the `id` field. Because the files are already sorted by the `id` I wanted to perform merge join (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join).

For that I need to have a way to load some portion of both files, process it and iteratively load more again from one or both files.
(The files are big and would not fit into memory so only streaming approach will work).

The problem is the Node API, what to use? `readline` will not work because of https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33463. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something quite similar recently and decided to use the `node-line-reader` module that has a simpler interface than the built-in `readline`. I then created a little recursive function that determines which file to read from next by comparing the `id` of each csv-entry of each provided file. After that the corresponding line gets written out to the target file, and the method is called again until all lines of all files are processed. Here's the whole class I ended up with:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const LineReader = require('node-line-reader').LineReader;

class OrderedCsvFileMerger {

    constructor(files, targetFile) {
        this.lineBuffer = [];
        this.initReaders(files);
        this.initWriter(targetFile);
    }

    initReaders(files) {
        this.readers = files.map(file => new LineReader(file));
    }

    initWriter(targetFile) {
        this.writer = fs.createWriteStream(targetFile);
    }

    async mergeFiles() {
        // initially read first line from all files
        for (const reader of this.readers) {
            this.lineBuffer.push(await this.nextLine(reader));
        }
        return this.merge();
    }

    async nextLine(reader) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reader.nextLine(function (err, line) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(line);
            });
        })
    }

    async merge() {
        if (this.allLinesProcessed()) {
            return;
        }
        let currentBufferIndex = -1;
        let minRowId = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.lineBuffer.length; i++) {
            const currentRowId = parseInt(this.lineBuffer[i]); // implement parsing logic if your lines do not start
            // with an integer id
            if (currentRowId < minRowId) {
                minRowId = currentRowId;
                currentBufferIndex = i;
            }
        }
        const line = this.lineBuffer[currentBufferIndex];
        this.writer.write(line + "\n");

        this.lineBuffer[currentBufferIndex] = await this.nextLine(this.readers[currentBufferIndex]);
        return this.merge();
    }

    allLinesProcessed() {
        return this.lineBuffer.every(l => !l);
    }
}

(async () => {
    const input = ['./path/to/csv1.csv', './path/to/csv2.csv'];
    const target = './path/to/target.csv';
    const merger = new OrderedCsvFileMerger(files, output);
    await merger.mergeFiles();
    console.log("Files were merged successfully!")
})().catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Any feedback regarding this?